# Order by in 2d array in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

There is an array of objects and each object also contains another nested array in angularJS. Typically there is 2-d array and I want to display the array value which will be ordered by the nested array named 'tasks'.

Here is my code.
Thanks is advance...

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]).controller('ctrl1', function($scope){
    $scope.record = [
         {uniqueID : 'pp-12', Name : 'Jim', status : 'Approved', tasks : ['xx', 'er'] },
         {uniqueID : 'pp-11', Name : 'Jim', status : 'Canceled', tasks : ['aa', 'vy','sd'] },
         {uniqueID : 'pp-45', Name : 'Nick', status : 'Pending', tasks : ['av'] },
         {uniqueID : 'pp-32', Name : 'Thomas', status : 'Canceled', tasks : ['zc', 'ym','at', 'lt'] },
         {uniqueID : 'pp-01', Name : 'Thomas', status : 'Pending', tasks : ['xy', 'fr'] },
         {uniqueID : 'pp-09', Name : 'Nick', status : 'Approved', tasks : ['aa', 'sd','cf'] },
         {uniqueID : 'pp-23', Name : 'Lina', status : 'Requested', tasks : ['av', 'bs','ay','tr'] },
         {uniqueID : 'pp-39', Name : 'Jim', status : 'Pending', tasks : ['zc'] }
    ];
 });



<table border="1">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Unique ID</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Status</td>
        <td>tasks</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody ng-repeat="data in  record">
    <tr ng-repeat="plan in data.tasks track by $index | orderBy : tasks" >
        <td> {{data.uniqueID}}</td>
        <td> {{data.Name}}</td>
        <td> {{data.status}}</td>
        <td> {{plan}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'ordered by'?

Comment: You want to sort the results by tasks values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can use only a loop, creating a new sorted array, Try:

```
.filter("recordFilter", function(){
  return function(records){
    var arr = [];
    angular.forEach(records, function(record){
      angular.forEach(record.tasks, function(plan){
        arr.push(angular.extend({}, record, {plan:plan}))
      })
    });
    return arr.sort(function(a,b){
      return a.plan > b.plan ? 1 : -1
    })
  }
})
```

```
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="data in record | recordFilter track by $index">
    <td> {{data.uniqueID}}</td>
    <td> {{data.Name}}</td>
    <td> {{data.status}}</td>
    <td> {{data.plan}}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/THQoPYxeNT29zagY8u6N?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

Nested ng-repeat?

```
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Unique ID</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Status</td>
            <td>tasks</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody ng-repeat="data in  record">
        <tr>
            <td> {{data.uniqueID}}</td>
            <td> {{data.Name}}</td>
            <td> {{data.status}}</td>
            <td> <span ng-repeat="plan in data.tasks"> {{plan}}</span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```