# Sort a nested Array (2D Array) array from filter of angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, multidimensional-array, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

How I Sort a nested Array (2D Array) array from filter of angularjs. It's very Complicated for Me. anybody can help. appreciated for me. thanks...

I have a 2D Array. now how I sort it within ng-repeat.

Template File...

```
<ul>
  <span ng-repeat="list in lists">

    <li ng-repeat="list_ in list.list1 | orderBy:'name'">{{list_.name}}</li>
  </span>
</ul>
```

JS file...

```
$scope.lists = [
{
  no : 1,
  list1 : [{
  name : 'A'
},
{
  name : 'M'
}]},
{
  no : 2,
  list1 : [{
  name : 'B'
}]},
{
  no : 5,
  list1 : [{
  name : 'Z'
}]},
{
  no : 3,
  list1 : [{
  name : 'X'
},
{
  name : 'T'
}]}
]
```

[plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/WtbxnZspHx6MElNjZhrl?p=preview)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could achievable by flatten the array will all the inner object at the same level using custom filter

**Markup**

```
  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCon">
    <ul>
      <span ng-repeat="list in lists | flatten | orderBy:'+name'">

        <li>{{list.name}}</li>
      </span>
    </ul>
  </body>
```

**Filter**

```
app.filter('flatten', function(){
  return function(array){
    var flattenArray = [];
    angular.forEach(array, function(value, index){
      angular.forEach(value.list1, function(val, index){
        flattenArray.push(val);
      })
    })
    return flattenArray;
  }
})
```

[**Plunkr Here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/E2z7ELOCt6hmIiKcsm8a?p=preview)

Comment: @Sandeep Glad to help you..Thanks :)

Comment: @Sandeep Accept means you need to click green mark beside the up & down arrow of my answer..look at this post for more details http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

to answer your question of how to sort a nested Array array with an angularjs filter, you actually are already doing so. It isn't clear with your data, so I expanded it to make it show what is happening already:

http://plnkr.co/edit/8SjuLc?p=preview

js

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCon", myConFun);
myConFun.$inject = ['$scope'];

function myConFun($scope) {
  $scope.lists = [{
      no: 1,
      list1: [{
        name: 'Z'
      }, {
        name: 'X'
      }, {
        name: 'Y'
      }, {
        name: 'A'
      }, {
        name: 'M'
      }, {
        name: 'C'
      }, {
        name: 'B'
      }]
    }, {
      no: 2,
      list1: [{
        name: 'B'
      }]
    }, {
      no: 5,
      list1: [{
        name: 'Z'
      }]
    }, {
      no: 3,
      list1: [{
        name: 'X'
      }, {
        name: 'T'
      }]
    }

  ]
}
```

html

```
<ul>
  <span ng-repeat="list in lists">
    <li ng-repeat="sublist in list.list1 | orderBy:'name'">
      {{sublist.name}}
    </li>
    ----------
  </span>
</ul>
```

output:

[image]

You may need to expand your question further if this isn't the behavior you need

Comment: thanks. but not sorting separate inner Indexes. i.e. all inner indexes sorting. like:
A, B, C, M, T, X, Y, Z

Comment: in that case, your question has been asked and answered already: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30677824/1078450